# match any column width and set

Tags: html, css

I have the below HTML table row set:

```
 <col class="colname-c1 colwidth-7"></col>
 <col class="colname-c2 colwidth-75"></col>
 <col class="colname-c3 colwidth-16"></col>
```

I apply CSS to them as follows:

```
.colwidth-7{colwidth-7%}
.colwidth-75{colwidth-75%}
.colwidth-16{colwidth-16%}
```

This is working fine as I did it in an excel by using the `concat` function for all the widths from 1-100. But I've been getting some column widths like this:

```
<col class="colname-c1 colwidth-7.27%"></col>
<col class="colname-c2 colwidth-75.76%"></col>
<col class="colname-c3 colwidth-16.97%"></col>
```

Here I want to know if there is a dynamic way of setting the css width? This is because I am not sure how many different types of col widths are there and there are approximately 290 tables that I need to create. Please let me know if there is a way for dynamically creating css.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First up, seems to me that the [`col` element spec](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/tabular-data.html#the-col-element) says it has no content and can not have a width itself. The only purpose [seems to be](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/col) to "define common semantics" on cells. If you want to set a width on columns in a table you'll have to do it through the (header) cells.

To continue with the actual question:

> I want to know if there is a dynamic way of setting the css width?

This can be done, but only for elements that can actually have a width.

Check out the [W3 Selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#selectors) page. One way to fulfill your requirement is as follows:

```
[class*="colwidth-75"] { width: 75%; }
```

This selects all elements with a class attribute value that contains the string "colwidth-75". See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lf42W/3/) for a demo.

There's no real reliable way AFAIK to dynamically set the value of width based on the class name, or anything similar. Some similar/related techniques that may shed some light on this for you are [LESS](http://lesscss.org/), [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/), and the new [CSS-Variables](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-variables/) module (draft phase).

You can also consider setting these CSS properties using client or server side script, but if that's possible will probably depend on your use case.

Comment: Updated the question as the `col` element doesn't quite work for setting widths. I've also updated to [a new fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lf42W/3/) that uses `th` instead of `div` so you can have the effect in a table.